# Adding a member to an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, class

I want to write a class (`ListDePersonnes`) that handles my array, currently I only have two methods, one to add objects and one to print the array contents to screen.

**`ListDePersonnes`**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListDePersonnes {
    int count,t;
    personne liste[];
    Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);

    public void initialize() {                  //
        System.out.println("entrer la taille"); //
        t = s.nextInt();                        // I'm not so sure about this part.
        personne[] liste = new personne[t];     //

    }


    public void addpersonne(){

        System.out.println("what is the name?");
        String nom= s.next();
        System.out.println("what is the age?");
        int age= s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("what is the weight?");
        double poid= s.nextDouble();

        liste[count] = new personne(nom,age,poid);  // weight is poid in frensh 
        count++;
    }



    public void showAll(){
        for (int i=0;i<t;i++ ){
            System.out.println("name: "+ liste[i].getNom() + " / age: "+liste[i].getAge()+" / poid:       "+liste[i].getPoid());
        }
    }
}
```

**`personne`**

```
public class personne {

    private String nom;
    private int age;
    private double poid;

    public personne(String nom, int age, double poid) {

        this.nom = nom;
        this.age = age;
        this.poid = poid;
    }

}
```

**`Main`**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class LaListe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        ListDePersonnes lper= new ListDePersonnes();
        lper.initialize();
        lper.addpersonne();
    }

}
```

The error thrown is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at ListDePersonnes.addpersonne(ListDePersonnes.java:29)
>       at LaListe.main(LaListe.java:16)

Comment: `personne[] liste = new personne[t];`. You are shadowing your class field variable. It should be  `liste = new personne[t];`

Comment: thanks a lot man , any idea on how to delete ?

Comment: take easy on me guys . i'm new to this :) lol SO becoming scary... Just format your code and show some effort, people won't downvote or close

Comment: @mprabhat last question a posted i was almoste got raped on the comment section lol

Comment: If you are looking for an easier thing to use then arrays, check out Lists (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html).

Comment: @IslamBouderbala Specific questions help too, makes it feel like less of a Google request.

Comment: @IslamBouderbala be happy now you have an upvote too :)

Comment: You may want to consider having a method to create a larger array to hold more Personne's if the user fills up the array. Or using a different data structure such as an ArrayList, they are very simple to use.

Comment: @Islam Bouderbala Do you mean how to delete person from array? Array have static length, so you have to create new array with length of `lenght-1` and then "copy" all `Objects` (except the one you want to remove) to new array. I recommend you to use `List`.

Comment: @MatthewC yes i'll try it with arraylist . so will you be generouse enough to show me how ?

Comment: @TheDubleM i think i'll go with arrayList as soon as figur out how to use it

Comment: thnx for everything guys

Comment: There's no need for me to show you, it's so simple! Haha. You initialize it like: ArrayList<CLASSTYPE> personnes = new ArrayList<CLASSTYPE>. CLASSTYPE refering to the type of data you're storing. So in your case, you replace CLASSTYPE with Personne. To add elements, you say arrayListName.add( new Personne() ); To delete, you say arrayListName.remove(index); And there's lots of other methods to make your life easier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're [shadowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable `liste`. Replace

```
Personne[] liste = new Personne[t];
```

with

```
liste = new Personne[t];
```

Comment: thanks a lot man , any idea on how to delete a personne from the array ?

Comment: If you need to delete an Object from the collection then you can use a `List`, e.g. `ArrayList`

Comment: do i declare it the same as i did with the simple array ?

Answer (score 2):

Java includes a class to do such operations more easily, List ([docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html)).

Example usage (from [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html)):

**To add an element to the list:**

```
List<Personee> listA = new ArrayList<Peronsee>(); //New ArrayList
listA.add(new Personee("Bob", 29, 165)); //Add element
listA.add(new Personee("Alice", 25, 124)); 
listA.add(0, new Personee("Eve", 34, 136)); //This adds an element to the beginning of the list, index 0.
```

**To remove an element:**

```
listA.remove(personee1); //Remove by object
listA.remove(0); //Remove by index
```

**To access/iterate over the list:**

```
//access via index
Peronsee element0 = listA.get(0);
Personee element1 = listA.get(1);
Personee element3 = listA.get(2);


//access via Iterator
Iterator iterator = listA.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext(){
  Personee personee = (Personee) iterator.next();
}


//access via new for-loop
for(Personee personee : listA) {
    System.out.println(personee.nom + "," + personee.age + "," + personee.poid);
}
```

Comment: from what i see . that's an arraylist . what should i do to get objects "personnes" list ?

Comment: @IslamBouderbala Updated my answer. The List interface can be made generic, (the `List<Personee>`) which limits the types that can be added and read from the list. In this case the `List` object can only handle objects of the `Personee` type.